# RegEx for matching substrings

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to write a regex to match on all substrings of a given input string. I have tried the following:

```
def sub_string(str):
    n = len(str)
    # For holding all the formed substrings
    output = "\\b("

    # This loop maintains the starting character
    for i in range(0, n):
        # This loop will add a character to start character one by one till the end is reached
        for j in range(i, n):
            output += str[i:(j + 1)] + "|"

    return output + "\\b)"
```

However, it matches on the wrong words. For example if i input "h" it matches. What could be the problem? And is there another approach I could use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us how you're calling this function, and how the output is used.

Comment: So you're looping through your input to construct a regex pattern consisting of every character the input contains, separated by alternation? What are you really trying to do here, from a high level perspective?

Comment: The parentheses aren't nested properly. As shown, the pattern is `\\b(...\\b)`, but shouldn't it be `\\b(...)\\b` instead?

Comment: The pattern always ends with a vertical bar, i.e. `abc` yields `a|ab|abc|b|bc|c|`, therefore your patterns are always "match this, or this, or this, or nothing".  So every pattern will match.